# Trigonometry on a complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

$\cos(x)=3 \Leftrightarrow e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=6 \Leftrightarrow e^{2ix}-1=6e^{ix} \Leftrightarrow e^{ix}=3\pm\frac{\sqrt{40}}{2} \Leftrightarrow x=\left(\ln\left(3\pm\frac{\sqrt{40}}{2}\right)\right)i^{-1}$

can someone tell me where i messed up ?

Answer (score 2):

In your first step, it's $e^{ix} + e^{-ix}$, that is, plus, instead of minus.

Comment: thanks, i messed up xd